# To have an Integer pointing to 3 ordered lists in Java

Tags: java, sorting, merge, data-structures

**Which datastructure would you use in the place of X to have efficient merges, sorts and additions as described below?**

## #1 Possible solution: one HashMap to X -datastructure

Having a HashMap pointing from `fileID` to some datastructure linking `word`, `wordCount` and `wordID` may be a good solution. However, I have not found a way to implement it.

---

I am not allowed to use Postgres or any similar tool to keep my data neutralized.
I want to have efficient merges, sorts and additions **according to `fileID`, `wordID` or `wordCount` for the type below.**

---

I have the type `Words` which has the field `fileID` that points to a list of words and to relating pieces of information:

**The Type**

```
class Words
===================================
fileID: int 
[list of words] : ArrayList
[list of wordCounts] : ArrayList
[list of wordIDs] : ArrayList
```

**Example of the data in**

```
fileID   word   wordCount   wordID
      instance1 of words
1        He     123         1111
1        llo    321         2
      instance2 of words
2        Van    213         666
2        cou    777         932
```

**Example of needed merge**

```
fileID     wordID                 fileID     wordID
1          2
1          3           wordID=2
2          2           ========>  1          2
2          3                      2          2
```

I cannot see any usage of set-operations such as [intersections](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/187123/) here because order is needed.

Having about three HashMaps makes sorting difficult:

1. from `word` to `wordID` in a given `fileID`
2. from `wordID` to `fileID`
3. from `wordID` to `wordCount` in a given `fileID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a class to store the word, word count and word id together? Then you would need a single list for each fileID. This would IMO at least simplify the operations.

```
class Word {
    private String text;
    private long count;
    private long id;
    // getters, setters
}

class Words {
    private int fileID;
    private List<Word> words;
    // getters, setters
}
```

This would be the skeleton, which already automatically resolves your mapping 3. Then you can add the needed additional mappings to `Words` and/or `Word`.

I don't understand from your description, whether the same word always have the same wordID, or can it have different IDs in different files; without this I can't move forward with the design idea. But I hope this so far helps you get over the stalemate :-)

Comment: This seems to be an excellent answer. However, I need to first make a few experiments for merges, additions and such to verify that its efficient.

Comment: Yes, the same word must always have the same wordID. It cannot have different IDs.